# MemberMissingException in FitSharp

Tags: c#, fitsharp, dbfit

When using a SUT in a `DoFixture` to explore its behaviour, the first call to a fixture-method succeeds but fails after invoking a SUT-method:

[image: Screenshot]

```
public class ConfigurationCharacterization : fitlibrary.DoFixture
{
    ConfigurationDelegator cd = new ConfigurationDelegator();
    public ConfigurationCharacterization()
    {
        mySystemUnderTest = cd;
    }


    public int AmountOfConfigsLoaded()
    {
        return cd.GetAllConfigs().Count;
    }
}

//delegates calls to the static methods of Configuration
public class ConfigurationDelegator : Configuration
{
    public new void Clear()
    {
        Configuration.Clear();
    }

    public new Configuration GetSingletonByIdentifier(string ident)
    {
        return Configuration.GetSingletonByIdentifier(ident);
    }

    public new List<Configuration> GetAllConfigs()
    {
        return Configuration.GetAllConfigs();
    }
}
```

`Runner.exe`, `fit.dll` and the fixture dll are all located in the same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out on [this github issue](https://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/issues/142), `GetSingletonByIdentifier` returns a `Configuration` object that gets wrapped in a DoFixture and processes the remainder of the table. The next call of `Amount of Configs Loaded` then tries to access the corresponding method of the class `Configuration`, this doesn't exist, hence the error.